# Convert curl command into Invoke-ResMethod or Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

The following command works in Ubuntu box:

```
curl -X GET "https://panorama.domain.com/api/?key=LUFRPTxxxxx&type=commit&action=partial&cmd=<commit><partial><admin><member>USERNAME</member></admin></partial></commit>
```

but it doesn't in the same box under powershell as:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri 'https://panorama.domain.com/api/?key=LUFRPTxxx&type=commit&action=partial&cmd=<commit><partial><admin><member>USERNAME</member></admin></partial></commit>' -Verbose:$true
```

I get:

```
VERBOSE: GET with 0-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 97-byte response of content type application/xml
Invoke-RestMethod: Invalid Credential
```

What am i doing wrong here? Do i have to split everything after `api` ?

Comment: What will be in output if you try `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://panorama.domain.com/api/?key=LUFRPTxxxxx&type=commit&action=partial&cmd=<commit><partial><admin><member>USERNAME</member></admin></partial></commit>").Content` ?

Comment: No content, as the response is: `Invalid credentials`. It doesn't even authenticate. I believe it's the way the URI is constructed.

Comment: If i run the curl command, the response is:
`<response status="success" code="13"><msg>The result of this commit would be the same as the previous commit queued/processed.
No edits have been made between these subsequent commits.
Please check the previous commit status. If still needed, use commit force instead.
</msg></response>`. I expect something similar to this in Invoke PS